# Feathers calling custom API method

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, feathersjs

I define my api with something like the below:

```
class MyFeathersApi {
  feathersClient: any;
  accountsAPI: any;
  productsAPI: any;

  constructor(app) {
    var port: number = app.get('port');

    this.accountsAPI = app.service('/api/accounts');
    this.productsAPI = app.service('/api/products');
  }

  findAdminAccounts(filter: any, cb: (err:Error, accounts:Models.IAccount[]) => void) {
    filter = { query: { adminProfile: { $exists: true } } }
    this.accountsAPI.find(filter, cb);
  }
```

When I want to use database adapter methods, from the client, i.e. find and/or create, I do the below:

```
var accountsAPIService = app.service('/api/accounts');
accountsAPIService.find( function(error, accounts) {
  ...
});
```

How I call custom methods, such as findAdminAccounts() from the client?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can only use the normal service interface on the client. We found that support for custom methods (and all the issues it brings with it going from a clearly defined interface to arbitrary method names and parameters) is not really necessary because everything in itself can be described as a resource (service).

The benefits (like security, predictability and sending well defined real-time events) so far have heavily outweighed the slight change in thinking required when conceptualizing your application logic.

In your example you could make a wrapper service that gets the admin accounts like this:

```
class AdminAccounts {
  find(params) {
    const accountService = this.app.service('/api/accounts');

    return accountService.find({ query: { adminProfile: { $exists: true } } });
  }

  setup(app) {
    this.app = app;
  }
}

app.use('/api/adminAccounts', new AdminAccounts());
```

Alternatively you could implement a [hook](https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers-hooks) that maps query parameters to larger queries like this:

```
app.service('/api/accounts').hooks({
  before: {
    find(hook) {
      if(hook.params.query.admin) {
        hook.params.query.adminProfile = { $exists: true };
      }
    }
  }
});
```

This would now allow calling something like `/api/accounts?admin`.

For more information see [this FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-create-custom-methods).

Comment: I guess, the wrapper service serves my problem. Right?

Comment: Yep, I think so. It's a little of a change in thinking from method based to a resource based approach but the benefits are worth it and it's what Feathers can do best.

Comment: Thank you. I am new to Node.JS in general, trying to comprehend multiple "technologies," including Feathers.JS, at once. Your help is truly appreciated.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to post your Feathers questions here, on Gitter (https://github.com/feathersjs/feathers) or on GitHub. We'll try our best to make learning it as easy as possible!

Comment: @Daff What about reusing methods in diferent services and hooks? For example, in my application I need to send a confirmation email to my user both when he first registers himself and also when he asks to send the confirmation email again. So, in this case I think I could create a service for sending emails, but I also think to call the same "sendEmail()" method/function in an after hook on the create user service. How can I make this work, so that my email be sent after the user registers and when he asks to receive the email again?